# Vertical center menu in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, menu, center, nav

I'm struggling with this problem for over an hour and can't get it right, I know these are basics but none solution from google helped, I don't understand what's the problem. I got that navigation bar and I want to vertically center logo and list elements inside it:

```
        <nav id="mainMenu">
        <a href="http://creativecorner.pl"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About me</li>
            <li>Portfolio</li>
            <li>Contact</li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

css:
http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/style.css

Here's the demo: http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/

@edit:

When I put margin-top:50% for #menu why it refers to entire body instead of nav element?

Comment: Tip top tip: If you link your own site to SO you should expect a spike in traffic that will bring down small sites :P. I suggest using jsfiddle instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice - the class name are different.  From your existing style, remove: #mainmenu, #menu, and #menu li.  Here is an example the code -> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HEaj7/1/)

Here is your new html:

```
<ul class="nav"> <a href="http://creativecorner.pl"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>

<li><a href="/">Home</a>

</li>
<li><a href="/about/">About me</a>

</li>
<li><a href="/work/">Portfolio</a>

</li>
<li><a href="/clients/">Contact</a>

</li>
```

Here is your new CSS:

```
.nav {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:red;
}
.nav li {
    display:inline;
}
.nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your "nav" element is fixed try wrapping your "ul" element in a div and setting the css of the margin to the distance you desire.

```
<div style="margin-top:20px">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About me</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The vertical spacing of block elements can be a bit tricky as they were never intened to behave that way. So some tricks are always required.

Answer (score 0):

You can center them to the middle by making the list and the logo's position relative, than giving them a 50% top and a negative margin with the half of their height. So just add these properties to the existing ones:

```
.logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
}

#menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
#mainMenu {
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #F00;
position: fixed;
line-height: 80px;  /*  added  */
}

#menu {
float: right;
margin-right: 16%;
display: inline-block;  /*  added  */
}
```